# Using Express as a proxy server with React.js returning 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I am trying to make request to a third party api from express, i want express to serve as a proxy, and send the result to the front end. the problem is that the route on the frontend has qyeries and parameters, this is my code

```
app.get("/api/posts/:id", function (req, res) {
request(
"https://api.xxxx.com/yyyy/1897970/user",
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: API_KEY,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
},
function (error, response, body) {
  const per_page = req.query.per_page;
  const page = req.query.page;
  const query = req.query.query;
  const id=req.params.id;
  if (!response.body) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    res.send({
      body,
      id,
      "per-page": per_page,
      page: page,
      query: query
      });
    }
   }
  );
 });
```

On the front end, i have to make request to a route like

```
 axios
  .get(
    `/api/posts/{id}/query?per_page=10&page=${title}`)
  .then((res) => { 
       
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log (err) })
```

The problem is that it returns an error 404, it cannot get the data, please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The URL in the get is not a full URL. change it to the full URL of your backend, if you are in localhost so localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its still the same response. Error 404

Answer (score 0):

Add proxy to the package.json in react client to fetch the data from the backend

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
```

the proxy should be the port on which the backend is running.

Comment: Thanks for the response. this has already been added. mind you, one of the routes work. only this doesnt